# How to convert elements to snake_case format in jsonb column array [Postgresql]

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.1, jsonb-array-elements

I have a database table(call it table) with jsonb column(lets say column). Column contains bellow data:

```
{
  "country": "GB",
  "channel": "mobile",
  "profileGroups: [
    {
       "profiles": ["profileA", "profileB"],
       "negativeProfiles: ["negativeA"
    },{
       "profiles": ["profileC"],
       "negativeProfiles": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to create view for this table with fields in snake_case format, so it should looks like:

```
{
  "country": "GB",
  "channel": "mobile",
  "profile_groups: [
    {
       "profiles": ["profileA", "profileB"],
       "negative_profiles: ["negativeA"
    },{
       "profiles": ["profileC"],
       "negative_profiles": null
    }
  ]
}
```

My latest query looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_table
SELECT json_build_object(
'country', column_1 -> 'country',
'channel', column_1 -> 'channel',
'profile_groups', column_1 -> 'profileGroups'
)::jsonb as column_1
FROM table;
```

How to transform data from inside of profileGroups array?

[Example at DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4mz2bosQ)

Comment: You have invalid JSON ! Can you fix it

Answer (score 2):

If the elements which you want convert are already known then we can use a bunch of nested `replace()` statements :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_table AS
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(column_1::TEXT, 'profileGroups', 'profile_groups'), 'negativeProfiles', 'negative_profiles')::jsonb AS column_1
FROM mytable;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/T7DCyq9P)